# Use Java to detect if device is plugged into computer

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if it is possible to detect whether or not my Android phone is plugged into windows, so that if it is, I can run another command?

By the way, I mean for a Java app that is on the computer not the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to use the adb tool that comes with the Android SDK, which will list connected debuggable devices.

Less simple is to list your connected USB devices directly and identify Android devices that way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is done with PdaNet, they use a client on the phone and a server on the computer to show you SMS in real time. So definitely it is possible, how easy it is.. id dependent on your understanding of hardware and hwo it works in an os.